# I want to skip the item in ng-repeat using ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, accordion, angular-ng-if

I am trying to use ng-if in ng-repeat for implementing Accordions. Based upon the condition value, the ng-repeat should skip some items in ng-repeat.

E.g. If the item.condition is true then only it should display accordion.
The code below is what I have so far and it is not working. Does it look right?

```
     <accordion close-others="true">
          <accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:2" ng-if="item.condition == "true"",ng-init="isopen=2">
                  <accordion-heading>
          {{item.label}}
            <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
                         ng-class="{'icon-arrow-up': isopen, 'icon-arrow-down': !isopen}"></i>
                  </accordion-heading>
              </accordion-group>
          </accordion>
```

Comment: Did you try and is it not working? What's the output...any error?

Comment: the error was because of "true" in ng-if="item.condition == "true"". I should be only true. Thanks :-)

Comment: @user3320018 No! No! No! If it's not working, it's off-topic for Code Review!

Comment: For here a valid question also means correct syntax....such problems are covered by editors. The OP should be made aware about that instead...a simple editor will flag such errors.

Comment: @user3320018 I don't think you get it. Codereview is for working code only. The user mentions this in his post: *"The code below is what I have so far and it is not working."*. Codereview is for ***working code only***. Broken code is off-topic there.

Comment: @user3320018 Being a regular on Codereview, I know this. If you need/want to know what is on, and off-topic there, you can read through the [on/off-topic page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @user3320018 Regardless of being off-topic here or not, it's not [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Code Review. Don't refer broken code to CR, ever.

Comment: TLDRing it, only code that works as expected is for code review. Broken code comes here. Working, but ugly, code goes to CR.

Comment: Agree not for code review but not for here either...the OP's code has **syntax error** and that's my point.

Comment: @user3320018 If it has a syntax error, then it's perfectly on-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @EthanBierlein One of the close flags states: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.` Syntax errors are usually typographical errors.

Comment: Well we also discourage code dump...especially with problems like this which shows lack of effort by OP. What does "perfect" mean?

Comment: @EthanBierlein - did you spot the syntax error in the code part of the question? `<accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:2" ng-if="item.condition == "true"",ng-init="isopen=2">` I didn't mean code review...I was trying to make a point about quality of question for here. Did you read the question completely the first time...along with the code? It has syntax error with `" , ` and besides the user `pankajparker` who answered this post noticed and has mentioned about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ng-if` contain double extra quotes, It should be `ng-if="item.condition == true"`, Also remove the `,` from the accordion element

Also you could minimize your condition to `ng-if="item.condition"` so then expression will return `true` and `false` on `item.condition` variable evaluation.

**Markup**

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:2" 
       ng-if="item.condition" ng-init="isopen=2">
        <accordion-heading>
            {{item.label}}
            <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'icon-arrow-up': isopen, 'icon-arrow-down': !isopen}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: Got it, it was because of  extra "" in  ng-if="item.amenity =="false"". Thanks :-)

Comment: I have one question, Instead of hard coded value for true of false in ng-if. I just want to pass variable that contains true of false eg:  check = "true or false".        ng-if "item.condition == check".  It is not working this way , is there any way ?

Comment: sure..`ng-if` needs only expression which should return true or false on evaluation of it.take a look at mine updated answer...

Comment: Thanks. But I my case i am using the above code as a directive. So, for some conditions  ng-if = "item.condition == false" and  ng-if="item.condition==true". So , i trying to the pass the false and true at run-time and make it work. Is there a way that i can pass variable for false or true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81684/discussion-between-mahesh-and-pankajparkar).